# How to post an array using AJAX to PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I want to post an array to PHP using AJAX and on success returns the value back to JavaScript. Here's my code.

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "phparray.php",
    data: {
        array1: phparray
    },

    success: function(data){
        alert("success");
        alert(data);
    }
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script>
     var phparray = jQuery.makeArray();
     for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++){
        phparray.push(i); 
     }

    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="phparraypost.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
$n=$_POST['array1'];

echo $n;


?>
```

The data I get back says

```
<br /> <b>Notice</b>: Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\php\phparray.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br /> Array
```

and I don't have an idea what might be wrong with it.

The HTML, PHP and JavaScript code are in different files.

Comment: So what isn't working exactly. Other than using jQuery to create an empty array, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong?

Comment: The 'path' between a client (javascript) and the server (php) is HTTP.  Http doens't care about arrays and only accepts strings. In your javascript you should format the array to a string (comma seperated, JSON) and parse it serverside to get the array back.

Comment: @Joren - jQuery will do that for you.

Comment: @adeneo that's why I didn't state is as an answer but as a comment.

Comment: the data i get back says "<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\php\phparray.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
Array" and i don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Use `var_dump` or `print_r`. You cannot use `echo` on objects and array

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your PHP - you are using echo on an array. Instead use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

```
<?php
    $n=$_POST['array1'];
    var_dump($n);
?>
```

Comment: how can i use $n in the form of an array in the php file? any suggestion, please!

Comment: Well `$n` should already be an array so you could easily traverse it with `foreach` etc. Try `var_dump($n)` and see what kind of data type is reported back (it should be Array).

Comment: var_dump($n) returns "array(10) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "2"
  [3]=>
  string(1) "3"
  [4]=>
  string(1) "4"
  [5]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [6]=>
  string(1) "6"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "7"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "8"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "9"
}
" I think I might just get what i wanted.... thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I came up with the solution using `$.param`. This function is used internally to convert form element values into a serialized string representation. I am not sure if it fulfills your requirement.

```
   <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        var phparray = new Object();
         for(var i=0; i<10 ; i++){
            phparray['val' + i] = i; //store value in object
         }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "phparray.php",
            data: {
                array1: $.param(phparray) //serialize data
            },

            success: function(data){
                alert("success");
                alert(data);
            }
        });
      });
    </script>
```

PHP

```
 $pieces = explode('&', $_POST['array1']); //explode passed serialized object
 $phparray = array();
 foreach($pieces as $piece){
   list($key, $value) = explode('=', $piece);
   $phparray[$key] = $value; //make php array
 }

 var_dump($phparray);
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/ does this for you, since your already using jquery..

Answer (score 0):

**use this:**

```
$("#formId").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var url = $(this).attr('action');
        $.ajax({
            url : url,
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            cache : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            type : 'POST',
            success : function(data) {
                $('#result').html('<div class="notes">Done</div>');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
```